# Como limpar os campos de um formulário em Django

Tags: html5, python-3.x, django

Estou estudando Django e estou seguindo um curso, que é a criação de um Controle de Gastos. Entretanto não estou sendo 100% fiel ao curso, estou fazendo algumas modificações. Meu problema é o seguinte, quando realizo um cadastro de uma transação, os campos do formulário não são limpos quando ele retorna à página inicial, como soluciono isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se for um formulário, tente com `autocomplete="off"` na tag `form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que após o `POST` está partindo da sua **index** e redirecionando para a própria **index** (tipo um `single page application`).

**Se for isso** você deve estar enviando o formulário que recebeu o `request.POST` (`form = NomeDoFurmulárioForm(request.POST)`), por isso o modal está abrindo com o formulário preenchido.

Tente criar 2 instâncias do formulário.

**Ex**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import GastosForm
from .models import Gastos


def home(request):
    # Formulário vazio.
    form = GastosForm()
    
    # Valores do banco para a tabela.
    table = Gastos.objects.all()
    
    # Verificando o método que foi enviado.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        # Formulário com os valores do modal.
        formPOST = GastosForm(request.POST)
        
        # Se o formulário é valido.
        if formPOST.is_valid():
            
            # Salvando os dados.
            formPOST.save()

            # Retornando o formulário vazio.
            return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': form, 'table': table})
        
        # Se houver algum erro (formulário não válido).
        else:
            
            # Retornando **formPOST** que é o formulário preenchido, juntamente com o erro.
            return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': formPOST, 'table': table})
    
    # Se o método é GET.
    else:
        # Retornado o formulário vazio.
        return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form': form, 'table': table})
```

**Ex**:

[https://repl.it/@natorsc/django](https://replit.com/@natorsc/django)

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!